# Return all values and alternate a null column

Tags: mysql, sql, null, coalesce, isnull

I have 6 columns in a table, and a column called uuid has a null value for some rows.

I want to return any null value with "" and return all columns and rows, I've search around and seen some solutions with IFNULL, COALESCE but i seem to get the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET uuid = '' WHERE uuid IS NULL;
SELECT * FROM table;
```

These two should do the trick or do you just want to replace the null for this one query only and not permanently change it to ''?

Comment: Oh yes it's just temporary

Comment: SELECT column1, column2, columnxyz, COALESCE(uuid ,'') from table is it then. Did you use it right?